# Firebase return position in list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application I am storing the leaders where basically they are having some amount of points for completing the tasks. I am able to display them in recycle view based on their score. But Ideally I would need to show for the user in which position he sits ( 1st 2nd 3rd etc.) What would be a most efficient way to do so. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to archive this it to order by the `Score` property:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Leaders").orderByKey("Score");
```

Please also take a look on official Firebase [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data).

Comment: I have ordering working fine. But how to pull the position of the child?

Comment: The sorting user by score was working fine before I asked my question :). The only thing I need to do now is to pull the leader board position of user. Which is my primary question.

Comment: There 2 possibilities. 1. If you are using a `List` to display the items in  your `RecyclerView`, than you can add in front of each item an number (int i = 0) and than increment it (`i++`) for each itereation. After this and before setting the `adapter` you can sort the items accordingly with your needs. The default order is ascending. 2. You can use an `HashMap` and order your items according to the key.